# Autotools: Is it possible to do Cross Linking of Shared Libraries

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, autotools, automake

I may be stupid but thinking that is it possible to do Cross Linking:

```
                               Lib A                            Lib A1
===========   Calling Func A ===========  A calls Func A1   =============
| EXE File |   ===>          |  Func A |   ============>    | Func A1    |
===========                  |  Func B |   A1 calls fun B   =============
                             ===========   <===========
```

EXE and Both Library are Under Development.

If possible then how to do?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I decided to completely remove my previous answer, after I researched and found evidence on both the libtool manual and the mailing list recommending against it.

Yes, you can have libraries depending on each other. You might end up with only static libraries (where it's ok to have undefined symbols), as not all platforms fully support cyclic dependencies on shared libraries.

Libtool has some code to handle complex dependency for shared libraries, but it's not fully ported to all platforms; you'll end up with the more conservative implementation (static libraries) even if you pass in `--disable-static --enable-shared`.

Comment: So, simply you want to say that First I compile the library with function of other library depends only and then compile the second library and then compile the first library again with the dependency to Second.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about that link dependency; I made a change, so the executable links against both, and libtool is explicitly instructed to not try to resolve symbols at link time.

Comment: I edit my answer to be more appropriate. It seems more recent libtool versions are more conservative, an old project of mine that did this with DLLs on windows won't compile to DLLs anymore. I'm assuming you wanted dynamic libraries, as static libraries don't need to have symbols resolved.